# How Can I Use An Extracted Dependency As A Dependency In Gradle?

Tags: gradle

Some of my dependencies are in Artifactory as zip files that have been distributed by a vendor.
The jars are required to compile and the dll/so and html templates are required for debugging/runtime.

Creating a dependency on local files is straightforward:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "${projectDir}/sec-lib", includes: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Extracting dependencies is straightforward too:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.thirdparty.sec-lib:1.0@zip'
}
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "${projectDir}/sec-lib"
    from configurations.compile
}
```

How do I use them together though?
I can change the zip to a new configuration so only that one is extracted:

```
configurations {
    zipCompile 
}
dependencies {
    zipCompile 'com.thirdparty.sec-lib:1.0@zip'
    compile fileTree(dir: "${projectDir}/sec-lib", includes: ['*.jar'])
}
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "${projectDir}/sec-lib"
    from configurations.zipCompile
}
```

However, the `copyToLib` task has to run in order for the dependencies to resolve but the dependencies need to resolve for the `copyToLib` task to run.

How do I fix this circular dependency issue?

I don't want to have to have a README that says "make sure you run this task first or the project wont compile or import into your IDE".

I also have multiple zip files like this I need to deal with.